# how to convert Future<List<String>> into a List<String> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a Collection of Tasks in Firebase that are basic Strings and I want to store them in a List so that I may display them In a ListView Builder, this is how I am fetching it from Firebase:

```
  Future<List<String>> getUserTasks() async {
    //empty list of Service Objects
    List<String> tasks = [];
    try {
      // Access the Firestore collection for tasks
      CollectionReference tasksCollection =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks');
      String uid = auth.currentUser!.uid;

      // Access the Firestore document for the user
      DocumentReference userTaskDocument = tasksCollection.doc(uid);

      // Get the document snapshot
      DocumentSnapshot userTaskSnapshot = await userTaskDocument.get();

      //   // Check if the document exists and contains the 'tasks' field
      if (userTaskSnapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic>? data =
            userTaskSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?;

        if (data != null && data.containsKey('tasks')) {
          // Return the list of tasks
          tasks = List.from(data['tasks']);

          return tasks;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching services: $e');
    }

    return tasks; //returning list of tasks
```

And then I have a Riverpod provider returning this:

```
part 'task_list.g.dart';

//this provider will return a list of String of all of the Users currently logged in Task Names
@riverpod
class TaskList extends _$TaskList {
  @override
  Future<List<String>> build() async {
    final dbhandler = DBHandler();
    return await dbhandler.getUserTasks();
  }
}
```

now the problem is I can't have this be a Future so I can use it in a Listview.Builder so I try to make it equal this variable In my ConsumerWidget:

```
 List<String> taskList = ref.watch(taskListProvider);
```

but it returns the error:

```
The argument type 'AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderImpl<TaskList, List<String>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<List<String>>'.
```

How would you convert it to a non Future so that it may be used in a ListView.builder?

Comment: use `await` before your futureMethod

Comment: can you elaborate further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riverpod will wrap the value to an [`AsyncData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncData-class.html), in which you can handle the loading, error, and data state using the [`when`](https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValueX/when.html) method:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
  final taskList = ref.watch(taskListProvider);

  return taskList.when(
    loading: () => Text('widget to show when loading'),
    error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('widget to show when error'),
    data: (data) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          final item = data[index];
          // ...
        },
      );
    },
  );
}
```

`data` is a `List<String>`, which is the value exposed by `taskListProvider` when the future completes.

Comment: and how would I handle the List being empty as there can also be no Tasks?

Comment: before `return ListView.builder` just make a check with `if (data.isEmpty)` and return something else